# Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException - Using an iterator in Java?

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I am trying to iterate over a set of information I have in a spreadsheet, my spreadsheet has three columns and 2 rows.

This is my code I am using to iterate over the information,

```
private List<DataRecord> allData = new ArrayList<>();

public DataRepository(String excelFilePath) {

    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            DataRecord record = new DataRecord();

            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                record.setCardNumber(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
                record.setCvv(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
                record.setPostcode(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());

            }

            allData.add(record);
        }

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<DataRecord> getAllData() {
    return allData;

}

public void setAllData(List<DataRecord> allData) {
    this.allData = allData;
}
```

This worked this morning and now it seems to throw the above exception and I am unsure why .

Thanks

This is the full stack trace

```
    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1205)
at java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1252)
at gov.uk.dwp.epayments.repository.DataRepository.<init>(DataRepository.java:43)
at gov.uk.dwp.epayments.service.PayService.<init>(PayService.java:11)
at gov.uk.dwp.epayments.controller.PaymentController.<init>(PaymentController.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace.

Comment: You probably have an extra or a missing column value that's throwing off the loop. Check your excel file data.

Comment: Include the sources of POI in your workspace to debug what exactly is happening in the iterator.

Comment: Unrelated, but a general tip: for the input stream, either use try-with-resource or close it in a finally block

Comment: Decided to remake the spreadsheet, Now im getting Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell even though the cell is formatted to text , argh

Comment: Only call Iterator.next() once inside your loop. Assign it to a temporary variable if you need to use the value multiple times inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

This block of code is not well done and is causing a call to next() before to be sure if there is next cell

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
    record.setCardNumber(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
    record.setCvv(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
    record.setPostcode(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
}
```

You are checking once if it has next item but advancing three times. (three next instances)

If you have no more than tree Cells per row you could use in this way (its only one of lots of possible solutions):

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
if(cellIterator.hasNext(){
    record.setCardNumber(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
}
if(cellIterator.hasNext(){
    record.setCvv(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
}
if(cellIterator.hasNext(){
    record.setPostcode(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
}
```

Comment: My code is now working, I am getting the error Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell . My variables are defined as strings and my cells in excel are formatted as text. Any idea on this issue?